# How to understand Gradle dependencies block?

Tags: java, gradle, dsl, gradle-dependencies

I am new to Gradle and have some confuse when learning Gradle.Say, I have a denpendency config:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
}
```

I realize that classpath is a configuration for dependency and the closure after dependencies is delegate to `DependencyHandler` object, and I referred the api of DependencyHandler found that it has a `Dependency add(String configurationName, Object dependencyNotation);` method， but why there is no `add` here? why can we add the dependency just like `configurationName "group:name:version:classifier@extension"` other than

```
dependencies {
    //classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'

    add ('classpath', 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3')
}
```

Anyone some explain please..
Thanks